# Make Markdown files accessible in SharePoint and Microsoft Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, navigation, pdf, wiki

We are planning to migrate our pre-written documentation from Confluence into a repo, converting everything to Markdown and image files.

The end result needs to conform to the following requirements:

- There are several hundred files, so the deployment process should be as automated as possible.
- Accessible in Microsoft Search (For example the top search bar in SharePoint and Teams)
- There needs to be some kind of navigation, kind of like in Docusaurus ([example from my local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE7Ds.png))

We have set up a CI/CD process in Azure DevOps that is easily able to convert all of our special PlantUML syntax to .svg files, and render Markdown to PDF, HTML and whatever else is needed.

We have tried:

- Setting up a Docusaurus environment. This, however, means that the content is not indexed by Microsoft Search.
- Uploading all files as PDF. This even works automatically via CI/CD, no extra effort needed. However, when we open the files, the entire page is covered by the PDF preview. The navigation is basically just the document library. This is not intuitive at all - The navigation should be to the side of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Microsoft Graph Connectors to bring external content into the index:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/connectors-overview

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/overview-microsoft-search#tailoring-microsoft-search-to-your-organization

As far as I know, for the navigation covered by the PDF preview, we couldn't change the default behavior.